# Why do I get an error when trying to give a lexer as input of CommonTokenStream in ANTLRv4

Tags: java, parsing, compiler-construction, antlr4, lexer

so I'm trying to create a launcher for my ANTLR4 parser in java and I get 'incompatible types' error when I try to run my code:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import static org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams.fromFileName;

public class TLLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            String inp = "input.txt";
            org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream in = fromFileName(inp);
            gramLexer lexer = new gramLexer(in);
            CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer); // ###HERE
            gramParser parser = new gramParser(tokens); // ###HERE
            parser.r();
        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

and i get the following errors.

```
incompatible types: gramLexer cannot be converted to org.antlr.runtime.TokenSource
incompatible types: org.antlr.runtime.CommonTokenStream cannot be converted to org.antlr.v4.runtime.TokenStream
```

can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

ALSO, since we're here, can you give me a good source to learn ANTRL? I need to somehow make an AST of the input code and convert it to another language but I'm having trouble **even understanding** how ANTLR works and how i could get it done.

Comment: what's is inside file ? ...maybe it's not written accordingly ANTLR specification

Comment: It's just an input code that is in a correct form according to the grammar file that I have. If you want I can attach both the grammar and the input files, but I don't think they're the problem really...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> import org.antlr.runtime.*;

You're importing the wrong runtime. `org.antlr.runtime` is the ANTLR3 runtime. The ANTLR4 runtime lives in `org.antlr.v4.runtime` (from which you're already using `CharStream` and `CharStreams`, but not `CommonTokenStream`).

Comment: Thank you. didn't even notice that! do you have any resources that would help me understand how all this works in java & how I can do the project that I mentioned?

Comment: @MohsenAmiriAmjad The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference and [the docs on github](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/index.md).